# Copy stack to array

Tags: java

This is a version of the algorithm I have:

```
public void copyStackToArray(Stack<Integer> stack) {
    int i = 0;
    while (!this.bestRouteStack.empty()) {
        this.array[i++] = stack.pop();
    }
}
```

(the bounds on the array are guaranteed to be okay here for my code)

I'm wondering if there is a library algorithm that does this, but a search turned up nothing.

Comment: Is `Stack` your own implementation or Java's?

Comment: Java's `java.util.Stack`

Comment: Check out its overloaded `toArray()` method.

Comment: `toArray(T[] a)` already does

Answer (score 8):

Stack subclasses Vector which already supports this, try this...

```
stack.toArray(array)
```

[Here is the Javadoc for this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#toArray%28T%5b%5d%29).

Comment: It's actually [inherited](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html#methods_inherited_from_class_java.util.Vector) from `java.util.Vector`, not `List` (your link even goes to the `Vector` docs).

Answer (score 3):

I found that when I used the `toArray` method, I got the results in the reverse order to what I expected. When I created this stack:

```
Stack<String> stack = new Stack<>();
stack.push("foo");
stack.push("bar");
```

I wanted an array like:

```
{"bar", "foo"}
```

Because of course, stacks are LIFO. If you pop each element off the stack, you would pop "bar" first, and then "foo".

Instead, `toArray` returns `{"foo", "bar"}`.

A solution is to use a `LinkedList` instead. There is a `push` method on LinkedList, it performs the same as `addFirst`, and the result will be a list whose contents (if you traverse it of course) are "bar" and then "foo". And it also has the `toArray` method which returns as expected.

---

Test case:

```
LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<>();
list.push("foo");
list.push("bar");
String[] arr = list.toArray(new String[0]);
Assert.assertArrayEquals(new String[] { "bar", "foo" }, arr);
```

Comment: Thanks for this insight. This bit me when I was converting a codebase from using Stack to LinkedList. The API is almost identical but the code relied on toArray(), which now returned the reverse of what was expected.